# Is there any alternative of Python Dictionary in C++ without using high level Data Structures?

Tags: c++, dictionary, key-value

I was actually working a projects of OOP in C++ and stuck in a problem to store keys and their associative values. Both keys and values are string type.
Here's the code I'm trying to write but still it's showing error.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
std::map<std::string,std::string> dest;
using namespace std;
dest["M"]  = "001";
dest["D"]  = "010";
dest["MD"] = "011";
dest["A"]  = "100";
dest["AM"] = "101";
dest["AD"] = "110";
dest["AMD"]= "001";
```

Comment: ***write but still it's showing error.*** What error? No errors here after putting the code in `int main()`: [https://ideone.com/svlKz2](https://ideone.com/svlKz2)

Comment: You have assignments not within a function, of course it'll error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use initialization at global scope:

```
/* const */ std::map<std::string, std::string> dest = {
    {"M", "001"},
    {"D", "010"},
    {"MD", "011"},
    {"A", "100"},
    {"AM", "101"},
    {"AD", "110"},
    {"AMD", "001"}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @ALI and welcome to stackoverflow.

C++ is not like Python, you have to show the compiler where to enter the file by implementing an `int main()` function.

I attach this [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) for you to have a look over

## Solution

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
std::map<std::string,std::string> dest;
using namespace std;

int main(){
   dest["M"]  = "001";
   dest["D"]  = "010";
   dest["MD"] = "011";
   dest["A"]  = "100";
   dest["AM"] = "101";
   dest["AD"] = "110";
   dest["AMD"]= "001";
}
```